# Passing a void* as a function parameter selects the wrong overload

Tags: c++, void-pointers

Looked all over and don't see this talked about in exactly the way I'm seeing it, so here goes.

I have a class with 7 Put() overloads to handle passing each of the built in primitive types and also a char* and a void*.  The correct overload is selected when passing a primitive or a char*, but when I pass a void* it selects the overload for char* instead.

The class also has 7 Get() overloads, and returns a bool to indicate if the entry doesn't exist.  So I have to pass the parameter by reference to get back the value (therefore the void* is changed to void*&).  When I add a call to this Get() the build gives the following error:

> error C2664: 'bool A::Get(EntryId,bool &,int)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'MyType *' to 'bool &'

So the compiler seems to think that a MyType* matches with bool&.  I added a (void*) casting before the parameter in the call, and I got the following error:

> error C2664: 'bool A::Get(EntryId,bool &,int)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void *' to 'bool &'

Far as I know I can define a function signature to take a void*&, so I am not sure why that is not the option being selected by the compiler?

Code example shown below.  Does anyone have a hint on these two issues (for Put() and Get())?  There is a work-around that I can use, but I'm just trying to understand what the issue is here.  Thanks for your help.

```
class A
{
    A();
    // Puts
    void Put(EntryId id, bool bVal);
    void Put(EntryId id, int iVal);
    void Put(EntryId id, long lVal);
    void Put(EntryId id, double dVal);
    void Put(EntryId id, const char * szVal);
    void Put(EntryId id, void * pVal);
    // Gets
    bool Get(DataStoreId id, bool & bVal);
    bool Get(DataStoreId id, int & iVal);
    bool Get(DataStoreId id, long & lVal);
    bool Get(DataStoreId id, double & dVal);
    bool Get(DataStoreId id, char *& szVal);
    bool Get(DataStoreId id, void *& pVal);
};

int main(int argc, void ** argv)
{
    A myObj;
    std::string * myString = new std::string("My string");
    myObj.Put(ENTRY1, myString); // calls Put(EntryId id, const char * szVal);
    myObj.Get(ENTRY1, myString); // compilation error for bool&
    myObj.Get(ENTRY1, (void*)myString); // compilation error for bool&
}
```

Comment: _"but when I pass a void* [to Put()]"_ -- your example code does not demonstrate passing a `void*` to `Put()`. Your example passes a `std::string*` to `Put()`, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What is `ENTRY1`, `EntriyID` and `DataStoreId` ?

Comment: does it actually matter? And do you not get same behavior with free functions instead of members? Please remove what is not relevant from the code

Comment: all methods are private btw

Comment: It seems fairly clear to me that this should be seen as two questions -- one that deals with `Put()` and *not* selecting the `void*` overload, and one that deals with `Get()` and the error *when* selecting the `void*` overload. Please limit yourself to one question per question.

Comment: I don't think the example code demonstrates what you're saying, but it's close enough that I can guess. I'll answer in terms of the code you posted.

Comment: `std::string * myString = new std::string("My string");`. Just don't do that. There is no reason to allocate `std::string` on the heap. Just say `std::string myString = "My string";`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you have the wrong type, and the error is telling you that you have the wrong type, try using the right type.

If you use the exact type the function expects, then you will call that function; otherwise it will find the one it can convert to. If there are none, then you get the error.

In the case of your "Put" functions, you have the wrong type "std::string*" which cannot be converted to "const char*", but the compiler finds that there is a potential match, because it can convert any pointer type to "void*". So it correctly does so.

To demonstrate the conversion rules, I have used a simple assignment, so you can view the error message in your compiler. Simply uncomment the line "pchar = myString;" Note that "pvoid = mystring;" does not generate an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Put(int id, const char* szVal) { std::cout << "put const char*" << std::endl; }
void Put(int id, void* pVal) { std::cout << "put void*" << std::endl; }
void Get(int id, char*& szVal) { std::cout << "get const char*" << std::endl; }
void Get(int id, void*& pVal) { std::cout << "get void*" << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, void** argv)
{
    char* pchar = nullptr;
    void* pvoid = nullptr;

    std::string* myString = new std::string("My string");
    // pchar = myString; 
    pvoid = myString;

    Put(1, myString);
    Put(1, "const char *");

    Get(1, pchar);
    Get(1, pvoid);
}
```

> put void*
> put const char*
> get const char*
> get void*

disclaimer: I am answering the question, and in no way endorsing this Get/Put design, especially not the use of void* without a length argument.